# I want add repository theme folder

Tags: plugins, php, themes

I create a plugins Wordpress with a theme. I want that my theme in my plugins folder. Exemple :

wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/theme/my-theme-wordpress.

I can hack wordpress for change repository theme Wordpress.

Thank You

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: In my plugin have one theme. Like this :

wp-content 
  -- plugins
    -- my-plugin
         -- my-folder-theme
             -- my theme

I want create a plugin with theme integrate.

It's clear ? 

For you response :)